# eclipse servlet debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I have written a servlet to perform some task .

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws IOException {
         String errmsg = "Could not retrieve workspace: ";        
        try {

            Object url1 = req.getParameter(PARAM_URL1);
            Object url2 = req.getParameter(PARAM_URL2);         
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/opt/local/bin/convert","pic"+url1 +".png","-shave","20x20","pic22.png");
            pb.directory(new File("/user/gaurav_kl"));
            pb.start();
            }
```

but the problem is when I debug the code in Eclipse using breakpoint I can't see the "req" and "resp" variable when I break inside the function.
Instead I am getting arg0 an arg1 as 2 variables which correspond to the "req" and "resp" variable.
Though I can use these also to debug,what might be the reason?
Also I am not able to view the values in "url1" and "url2" variable
I can see the "req" variable in other servlets of my project.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to recompile/redeploy.

Comment: i have done that.the thing is i compiled this class separetle while the other classes were genereated when I ran "ant" on the project.

Comment: I guess that ant is doing something different than your separate compile is doing.  Probably something like a package/deploy step you are missing.

Comment: yes.there was a "package" option in the "ant" script.How can I solve this.Do I need to add this class to the ant-build or is there other way

Comment: Sounds to me like the debugging information is missing from the class file. The amount of debugging information can be configured for each compile.